# View All button shows hidden divs, then changes to 'view less' - how to get the 'view less' to re-hide the previously hidden divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a 'view all'/ 'view less' function to hide and show divs.

Using Jquery, I managed to create a showAllFunction function that shows the hidden divs, when you click the button. Then, the text of the button changes from 'view all' to 'view less' and a new class name is given to it.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").attr("onclick","showAllFunction()");
});


//show all function
function showAllFunction(){
  $("#blocks-item:nth-of-type(1n+3)").css("display","flex");
    $(".knowledge-base").css("min-height", "fit-content");
    $(".btn1").html("View Less");
}
 //hide all function
 function hideAllFunction (){
  alert('Robbie = awesome')
  $("#blocks-item:nth-of-type(1n+3)").css("display","none");
  $(".btn1").html("View All");
  $(this).removeClass('btn1pressed').addClass('btn1')
};
```

[image shows display of divs - some divs are hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTPA7.png)

[Image shows display of divs - all divs are shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbZ3i.png)

Sadly, I am not very experienced and do not understand how to get it to change the functionality so that, when I click 'View less' button, it will re-hide the previously hidden divs.

The mark-up is .hbs:

```
 <section class="section knowledge-base">
    <h2 class="categories-heading">{{ t 'categories' }}/Projects</h2>
    <section id="categories-blocks">
      <ul id="blocks-list">
        {{#each categories}}
        {{#if ../has_multiple_categories}}
        <li id="blocks-item">
          <a href='{{url}}' id="blocks-item-link">
            <span id="blocks-item-title">{{name}}</span>
            <span id="blocks-item-description">{{excerpt description}}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        {{else}}
        {{#each sections}}
        <li id="blocks-item">
          <a href='{{url}}' id="blocks-item-link">
            <span id="blocks-item-title">
              {{name}}
            </span>
            <span id="blocks-item-description">{{excerpt description}}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
        {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
      <div class="categories-blocks-view-all">
        **<button class='btn1' role="button">View All</button>**
      </div>

      {{pagination}}
    </section>
```

Comment: does it help http://jsfiddle.net/8u2jF/

Comment: Can you please add your HTML to the question as well?